# python: zip file iterators together that extract lines by next

Tags: python, list, io, iterator

Have multi-line data files, e.g. like `f1`:

```
name1
34
name2
12
name3
331
```

and `f2`:

```
name1
0.34
name2
0.1
name3
1.0
```

In order to parse a single file I use the idiom like:

```
with open(f1, "r") as f1: 
    while True:      
        name, data = next(f1), next(f1)
        # Do something with name and data...
```

How can I use the same pattern to read "paired" files like `f1` and `f2` ?

```
def multi_parser(f1, f2):
    with open(f1, "r") as f1_in, open(f2, "r") as f2_in:    
        while True:
            name, data = list(zip(next(f1_in).rstrip(), next(f2_in).rstrip())), 
                         list(zip(next(f1_in).rstrip(), next(f2_in).rstrip()))

            # Do something with name and data...
            print(list(name))
            print(list(data))
```

It seems like the code is to greedy, the first print of `name` and `data` gives:

```
[('n', 'n'), ('a', 'a'), ('m', 'm'), ('e', 'e'), ('1', '1')]
[('3', '0'), ('4', '.')]
```

Where I expected something like:

```
[('name1', 'name1')]
[('34', '0.34')]
```

Comment: What's with the naked except?

Comment: Could be something else - it just does not give any warning or anything. I should not have anything to do with my unexpected result though

Comment: `zip` accepts iterables and returns columns of items. In this case you're passing strings and that's why you're getting characters. All you need is passing the file objects to the `zip`. `zip(f1_in, f2_in)` or if you want to strip the lines do : `zip(map(str.rstrip, f1_in), map(str.rstrip, f2_in))`

Comment: I need to do something per record (i.e. per each two lines)

Comment: @user3375672 That's what you can do with `zip` if you are using python 3.x `zip` returns an iterator object which means that you can loop over it and get the pairs on-demand.

Comment: @Kasramvd `zip(f1_in, f2_in)` was already suggested as a solution, I pointed out it would only give one line from each file instead of **two lines from each** and the poster deleted the answer.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Well you can use `zip` then just do a `next` after each iteration, or use another `zip` with `itertools.islice`. `zip(islice(pre_ziped, 0, None, 2),islice(pre_ziped, 1, None, 2))`

Comment: @Kasramvd again, if you think you can answer the question post an answer, this discussion in comments is getting ridiculous.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I still don't follow why `zip(f1_in, f2_in)` fails; yes you only get 1 line at a time, can't you just alternate between `name` and `data` or do I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: It at least fails to give the iteration the OP is expecting (where two names and values are available for each iteration of the loop) However @Chris_Rands it now occurs to me that using it with `name,data = next(zipped), next(zipped)` would do what they wanted...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `next` returns strings and you iterate over them (which gives you the single character pairs). You could just use literals for the `list` and `tuple`:

```
name, data = [(next(f1_in), next(f2_in))], [(next(f1_in), next(f2_in))]
```

Or if you want to avoid all these `next` calls:

```
f1_in, f2_in = iter(f1_in), iter(f2_in)  # make sure f1_in and f2_in are iterators

for name1, name2, value1, value2 in zip(f1_in, f2_in, f1_in, f2_in):
    name = [(name1, name2)]
    data = [(value1, value2)]
```

Comment: It's is not efficient to call the `next` for each line. You can simply `zip` the file objects.

Comment: @Kasramvd: could you elaborate ?

Comment: @user3375672 Read my comment on your question. Regarding the `next` it's only useful when you want to get first or some of the leading items from an iterable not all the lines that's insane :).

Comment: @Kasramvd Yes, but the question states "How can I use the same pattern to read "paired" files like f1 and f2 ?". Also it should be good/performant enough for files with less than several thousand lines.

Comment: @MSeifert It's not a good way, that's the point. Also I don't see any restrict relation between the title and this answer, there might be another better ways with same patter, even it doesn't sound rational.

Comment: @Kasramvd `next` is needed when dealing with `iterables` that can't be handled by a simple for loop, if you have a solution to iterate over two lines in a file at a time without using `next` you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Should say that my files can be GB large - cannot fit in memory

Comment: @Kasramvd I updated the answer. That was what you meant, right?

Comment: @MSeifert Yes, I think this is correct since it will consumes the items interleave.

Comment: The 2nd solution is exactly what is required I think +1

Comment: @MSeifert: would your 2nd solution consume every two lines of `f1` and `f2` at a time - in case the file are huge ? Does zip simply "add" a line (aka next) for each item in the for statement ?

Comment: @user3375672 As long as `f1_in` and `f2_in` are iterators and (file objects are iterators) the `zip` will consume two lines each iteration.

Comment: Might be worth adding a check for the more generic case, like `if not isinstance(f1,collections.Iterator): f1 = iter(f1)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands I generally prefer just doing `f1 = iter(f1)` without the `isinstance`-check. :)

Comment: So one take-home message is that a for-loop using `zip` is more efficient for multi-line records file parsing (when files are huge) than `next`  ?

Comment: Yes, because the `next` is implicitly called in `zip` (as C code) instead of explicitly (as Python code). At least in CPython.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend splitting up the code, first create a generator function that will generate the two elements at a time:

```
def pairs(file):
    try:
        while True: #broken by StopIteration
            yield next(file), next(file)
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

This way to iterate over a single file you can use a for loop:

```
for name, data in pairs(f1):
    print(name, data)
```

Then to iterate over two files at the same time you can just as easily do it with `zip`:

```
for (name1, data1),(name2,data2) in zip(pairs(f1),pairs(f2)):
    print(name1, data1)
    print(name2,data2)
```

---

It occurs to me that my definition for `pairs` is the same as:

```
return zip(file, file)
```

So you would technically be able to do the iteration you want as:

```
for (name1, data1), (name2, data2) in zip(zip(f1,f1),zip(f2,f2)):
    print(name1, data1)
    print(name2, data2)
```

But I wouldn't recommend that without defining the `pairs` function (even if it's just a single return) and well commenting it.

Comment: Now it's better (+) but as MSeifert suggested you can just pass file objects to one `zip`.

Comment: I'm not a fan of that idiom, it's one of the only things that works with iterators but not iterables. (but wouldn't raise a useful error)

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises, because you are passing two strings to `zip`, namely the respective lines of the file. `zip` then returns an iterator over pairs of characters of these strings:

```
list(zip("asdf", "ghjk"))
```

gives

```
[('a', 'g'), ('s', 'h'), ('d', 'j'), ('f', 'k')]
```

As you want a tuple of the full lines, you can just do:

```
name, data = ([(next(f1_in).rstrip(), next(f2_in).rstrip())], 
              [(next(f1_in).rstrip(), next(f2_in).rstrip())])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_iter(f1, f2):
    while True:
        yield [next(f1).strip(), next(f2).strip()], [next(f1).strip(), next(f2).strip()]


with open('f1', 'r') as f1, open('f2', 'r') as f2:
    for name, data in my_iter(f1, f2):
        print(name)
        print(data)
```

And you can get result like the following:

```
['name1', 'name1']
['34', '0.34']
['name2', 'name2']
['12', '0.1']
['name3', 'name3']
['331', '1.0']
```